# cerrar de un navegador la session si se abrio en otro php js

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

que tal quiero saber como dejar una session unica con php y js la forma de poder cerrar la session si abri en una maquina mi session y en otro maquina mi misma session es decir que no se dupliquen las sessiones activas

este seria chrome

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y este seria edge

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este seria el codigo que simplifique solo para cuando alguien se logea

```
<?php

include("../conecta.php");
session_start();

$nom=$_SESSION['usuario'];



if (!isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) {
    header("Location: index.php");
       echo'<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Debes iniciar sesion");
    window.location.href="index.php";
    </script>';

  exit();
}

if (!isset($_SESSION['tiempo'])) {
    $_SESSION['tiempo']=time();
}
else if (time() - $_SESSION['tiempo'] > 1200000) { /*Original tiene esté tiempo son 20 minutos*/
    session_destroy();
    /* Aquí redireccionas a la url especifica */
    header("Location: index.php");
    die();  
}
$_SESSION['tiempo']=time();


?>
```

Comment: Tu pregunta es muy amplia y basada en opiniones lo cual generaría su cierre

Comment: pero solo quiero cerrar una session cuando la abro en otro navegador

Comment: Eso lo entiendo, pero no existe respuesta única y en función de lo que conozca cada usuario será la respuesta y todas serían igualmente válidas, por eso lo que comenté, te invito a investigar, tratar algo y entonces publicar alguna duda pero con una estructura ya avanzada

Comment: Podrías guardar una variable en la tabla de usuarios al iniciar sesión que almacene la IP/MAC o algun dato especifico de la sesión. Luego al entrar en cada página comprobar si el dato en $_SESSION["logged"] es igual al de la base de datos y si no, cerrar la sesión. Así si alguien se vuelve a logear, el dato en la BBDD cambia y cierra la sesión que tenga el dato antiguo.

Comment: ok y para guardar esa IP/MAC de donde la tomo

Comment: En vez de usar IP/MAC, podrías usar un código generado aleatoriamente: rand(1,9999999999); (imprime un numero aleatorio de 10 digitos). Luego guardar el código en la tabla usuarios al iniciar sesión y creas también una $_SESSION["logged"] con el dato almacenado. Luego cada vez que el usuario acceda a una página compruebas que el $_SESSION["logged"] sea igual que el parametro en la BBDD y si no cierras la sesión.

Comment: Respecto a usar la IP/MAC, si usas la IP y el usuario abre sesión en otro ordenador de la misma red, no funcionará. Si usas la MAC y el usuario abre sesión en otro navegador no funcionará. Es mejor usar un código aleatorio o algún otro parámetro que sea único por sesión.

Comment: El "como hacerlo" dependera de cada persona, pero, si analizas lo que quieres, ya deberias tener la respuesta... cada vez que un usuario se "logea" debes eliminar todas las otras sesiones que ese usuario tenga (o pudiera tener) abiertas, de tal manera que cuando valides el siguiente "request" contra una sesion y la sesion no exista, invalides el movimiento, pero es definitivo que necesitas usar un identificador unico de sesion en la tabla de usuarios